# Is custom domain for old google sites available only with G Suite?

Tags: google-sites, google-workspace

Some time ago old google sites could be     connected with my custom domain.
Now when I try to add my domain to google site page I get an error to verify my domain with Google. However the instructions points to G Suite which is not free
https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=pl

Is custom domain not free anymore for google sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I found online you should still able to make your old google site have a custom domain for free, and then transfer it to the new google sites if needed. Here's the [link](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6069257?hl=en) where I found the answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that was the right answer, now when they are exposing G Suite this feature is well hidden :)